# Estimate probablity: Chernoff bound

Tags: probability

Two players $A$ and $B$ are playing following game:
They throw cube. When thrown number $k$ and $k$ is even then player $A$ get $k$ points.
When thrown number $k$ and $k$ is divisible by $3$ then player $B$ get $k$ points.

Show that with probablity $\ge \frac{999}{1000}$ after $60000$ throws player $A$ will have a $25000$-points lead.

I know that I should use Chernoff. But I have problem with defining binary variable.
Could you help me please ?